# Checking Internet Connection In Between Process in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have the following code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wallpaperswide.com/download/flattened_grass-wallpaper-2800x1050.jpg"];  //Line1
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];  //Line2
UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];  //Line3
NSLog(@"%@",tmpImage);  //Line4
```

In line2 to it will take some time to download image in that url...in between i have to check the internet connection..how it is possible?

i will explain my problem in detail....

upto line1 the internet connection is there for my iphone. now the line2 is executing...while the downloading process is going on , at the middle of this process, i lost my internet connection..

Now how can i notify the user as "You have no internet connection"...

so how can i check the Internet Connection In Between this Process.?

is there any delegate methods for it...please help me

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer for my Question...i'm pasting here for the future reference

**Declare a global variable**

```
NSMutableData *receivedData;
```

**In ViewDidLoad:**

```
receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
NSURLRequest *theRequest =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wallpaperswide.com/download/flattened_grass-wallpaper-2800x1050.jpg"]];


NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if (theConnection)
{
}

else
{
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    UIAlertView *connectFailMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"NSURLConnection " message:@"Failed in viewDidLoad"  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [connectFailMessage show];
}
```

**NSURLConnection Delegate Methods..**

```
#pragma mark NSURLConnection methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
[receivedData setLength:0];
 }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // inform the user
UIAlertView *didFailWithErrorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"NSURLConnection " message: @"didFailWithError"  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[didFailWithErrorMessage show];

//inform the user
NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
      [error localizedDescription],
      [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
  myImageView.image=tmpImage;
 NSLog(@"%@",tmpImage);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
if (netStatus == NotReachable) {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Could not connect to the server, please check your internet connection !" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];


}
else
{

 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kaushal Bisht.....But i think you are not getting my problem...How to check the internet connection while downloding problem process is going on(To handle losting of internet connection at the middle of download process at the line2).

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is to use `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. If there is an error on the connection, I will then use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html), to see if there is a problem with the internet, or if it was a server error.

Comment: Thanks @Jacky Boy.....But i think you are not getting my problem...How to check the internet connection while downloding problem process is going on(To handle losting of internet connection at the middle of download process at the line2).

Comment: I think I understood what you want, you just can't do it with your solution: `[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]`.

Answer (score 1):

NSURLConnection NSURLConnectionDelegate
NSURLRequest *theRequest＝［NSURLRequest requestWithURL：
                  ［NSURL URLWithString：@“http://www.sina.com.cn/”］
                 cachePolicy：NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                 timeoutInterval：60.0];
NSURLConnection *theConncetion=[[NSURLConnection alloc]
                   initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if(theConnection)
{

receivedData＝[[NSMutableData data］ retain］；
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error

Comment: Thanks @user2098756 But it should deal with image in a url http://wallpaperswide.com/download/flattened_grass-wallpaper-2800x1050.jpg.....        how i save the image into uiimage...

Comment: http://cagt.bu.edu/w/images/8/8b/URL_Connection_example.txt THIS may help ,when load finished UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData];

Answer (score 1):

Here the possible ways...

1) Using NSURLConnection Delegate Methods.

2) Using Rechability classes

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Reachability class modified of Tony Million that you can find at [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

You can use this to define blocks which gets invoked when reachability changes. So you can use it to show an UIAlertView.

If you want to download the image asynchronous i would recommend to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).
It already provides the possibility to add a ReachabilityStatusBlock to the AFHttpClient used.

So you can rewrite your code if importing AFNetworking.h to:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wallpaperswide.com"]];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFImageRequestOperation class]];

[client setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    if(status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable){
        NSLog(@"Not reachable");
    }
}];

AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:[client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/download/flattened_grass-wallpaper-2800x1050.jpg" parameters:nil] success:^(UIImage *image) {
    NSLog(@"%@", image);
}];
[operation start];
```